# Multiple SPI devices using single select line?

Tags: spi

I wish to send data back-and-forth between a Master and one of a few dozen slaves within a mesh-network style arrangement.

Assume that all units are (identical) microcontrollers within my control, i.e., can be programmed. In the interest of maximizing data throughput to several hundred kb/s, I am considering SPI.

Are there any strategies or existing implementations to achieve such a topology while using only 1 or 2 pins/signal-lines in total, aside from MOSI, MISO, and CLOCK?

These 1 or 2 pins could be for a custom handshaking or slave-selection method, however what I don't want to do is spend one pin per EACH slave (or use multiplexing) due to some constraints, including the wiring arrangement and limited physical space on the hardware of each master and slave.

I see I2C raising its hand here, but would like to maintain the advantages of SPI (e.g., simplicity and much faster data transfer). I expect throughput would decrease somewhat in this kind of bus implementation especially if I use software-addressing/polling, but perhaps there is some smarter solution to not drag it down too much?

Comment: Depending on the devices, it is possible to daisy chain SPI.

Comment: @PeterSmith : Any comments about pros/cons? How much does daisy chaining impede transfer speed in a system with several dozen slaves? I've heard about it being used with ADCs, which is a positive sign.

Comment: It simply means that each transaction must run through all the daisy chained devices (so more data per transaction); some devices support it, others do not. If you list the devices we could give a view on that.

Comment: @PeterSmith: Ah, I made a quick-edit to the question to mention that the devices are all microcontroller that are within my control, i.e., I can custom-program the communication as I wish.

Comment: Daisy chaining would work but it means that full frames of SPI transmissions need to include slots for every possible device each time you want to target a communication. Not really a very robust solution if performance is important.

Comment: You might want to check out SafeSPI https://safespi.org/specification/

Comment: @FRob how's that relevant? I don't see anything in documents to address this question.

Comment: @domen It's relevant because SafeSPI includes multiple slaves on the same #CS line using an addressing scheme similar to what other comments/answers recommended. Instead of making up your own addressing, why not use a standardized one?

Comment: @FRob yes, a side note mentions also this addressing scheme. It's nothing fundamental to SafeSPI and not even required by it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution here is to use SPI in an intelligent manner with embedded addressing. Each of the slave devices would be deployed with some type of device selection code using one of the following techniques:

1. Have a small 6 or 8 position "dip switch" that can be set to the address in binary format.
2. Use small rotary selector switches that encode a 4-bit value based upon the 0 -> 9 setting of the selector. Two of these can select addresses from 00 to 99.
3. Have a setup mode in the slave where you interactively set the address and save it into non-volatile memory such as EEPROM or FLASH in the slave device.

When you devise your SPI protocol set it up so every slave device is connected in parallel so all receive the SPI_SEL, SCLK and MOSI signals. They are all also connected to MISO but keep their output driver tristated until they are addressed.

You utilize the SPI_SEL as a framing control so that all the slaves are alerted to the start of a SPI frame when the SPI_SEL signal goes to its active level. The first byte of the SPI data clocked out from the master on the MOSI is the address value for the desired slave device. All the slave devices compare the address received against their specified address. Upon a match the addressed slave will enable its output onto the MISO line and remain actively connected until the SPI_SEL goes to its inactive level.

This scheme adds very little overhead to the overall SPI bandwidth and makes the connection wiring easy to implement. Since it seems that each of the many slaves are all on separate boards it may become necessary to buffer the interface lines so that the fanout to all the slaves has enough drive to properly operate the interface. One way to do this if longer distances are possible is to deploy the usage of differential drivers and receivers on the signal lines such as in a common chip like as an RS422 type transceiver. A chip that would work well to create the differential interface would be the TI SN75C1168. Two of these at each slave would provide the receivers for SPI_SEL, SCLK and MOSI. The one of the drivers can support the MISO signal with its tri-state control. The same two chips can be used at the master side to provide for the needed three drivers and one receiver on that end of your differential SPI bus.

[image]

<sup>*(Picture Source: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn75c1168.pdf)*</sup>

Comment: "Upon a match the addressed slave will enable its output onto the MISO line and remain actively connected until the SPI_SEL goes to its inactive level" --> Elegant solution, especially this part, thank you.

Comment: About your suggested setup: I also wish to put the Master in a low-power/sleep mode when not sending data. To allow a Slave that has new information to send to the sleeping Master, I'm thinking I could set the SPI_SEL line as an input (hardware interrupt-capable) on the Master prior to sleeping. That way, the Slave which wishes to send new data can assert the SPI_SEL line high, waking up the Master. The Master in turn clocks out an SPI transfer to which the Slave responds with the new data. Thoughts?

Comment: @boardbite - It may be possible to make that work with the SPI_SEL but I think it adds more complication than it is worth. If it were me I would poll the slaves periodically to see if they have data/events to report. Alternatively you could just add an additional wire that is from all the slaves back to the master that is an interrupt/wake signal. You could encounter some difficulty with trying to wire-OR the interrupt/wake line from all the slaves. You would have to use the driver enable at the slaves to enable the interrupt/wake signal and keep the input to the driver (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) tied to GND or VDD. This way if there were multiple slaves asserting the interrupt/wake they would all be placing the same levels on the lines of the differential interface. However I see little value to having this interrupt/wake because once the master comes active it still has to poll all the slaves to see who was signalling. There is also some question of value in putting your master MCU in sleep mode. You may not be saving that much energy if the extra circuity that it takes to support the interrupt/wake consumes any amount of energy itself. (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) Keep in mind that using a differentail bus itself will consume energy due to the typical 120 ohm resistors that are connected between the differential pairs at each end of the bus. The RS422 parts themselves are fairly low current in the idle state except for the current the driver has to inject and then sink to/from the termination resistors.

Comment: You could set up a half-sleep mode by polling the slave at larger intervals. Like once every three seconds. Consumption should be minimal.

Comment: Also note that the address can be any length you want and other bits can be used for payload. If you have up to 16 devices, 4 bits are enough, up to 32 devices 5 bits, up to 64: 6 bits and so on.

Comment: To deal with interrupts, you can have an interrupt-poll mode by reserving at least one address for it and making the MISO line open-drain (or its differential equivalent). Then any interrupting slave just needs to set its corresponding bit to zero in response to the polling. The simplest implementation would require 32 bytes for 256 slaves, but by using separate interrupt query addresses, this can be greatly reduced.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: The distance is not that large; the farthest unit of the (realistically 20 at most) units is ~30cm from Master, and all the boards need to be tiny (very space constrained), so I wonder whether differential drivers+receivers are even necessary. Also, about fanout, I am curious to hear your thoughts: wouldn't it be enough to use a line-driver on the Master board for the SPI_SEL line alone, since all the non-targeted slaves would be passive and thus the MOSI and MISO lines are active only a *single* Slave and Master until the SPI_SEL line is toggled to end the "conversation"?

Comment: For a total wiring distance of 30cm, and particularly if all devices share a decent DC grounding system, you probably would not see much benefit to the use of the differential drivers and receivers. For fanout the Master will need a decent driver as it has to drive the 20+ loads of all devices on the SPI_SEL, SCLK and MOSI lines. That loading is mostly going to be capacitive in nature and your desired high data rates will require needing to be able to swing the lines up and down with as fast of rise time required for your data rate. Ringing may become a problem on unterminated (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) signal lines so plan for a small value resistor in series with each of the driver outputs (22 ohm to start with) to provide series back match termination of the lines.

Comment: (continued from above) If you do intend to use the embedded addressing in the SPI protocol then all of the slaves will be actively listening to all the SPI SCLK and MOSI traffic and not totally passive. Each slave, when it is selected, will have to provide active drive on the MISO line. That line will have the same 20+ loads on it and so should also have a tri-state capable line driver due to the need to properly drive the high capacitance of the MISO. I would also equip each of these drivers with the series termination resistor in case it is needed. If not replace with a zero ohm resistor.

Answer (score 1):

Two methods come to mind.

1. Use a digital I/O expander to create additional slave-select lines.  Control the expander through that same SPI bus.  Slave-select the expander itself using that single SPI slave-slect line that's available from the microcontroller.
   Do a separate SPI transaction to set the I/O expander, before talking to the "payload" device.
2. If you have two lines (in addition to MISO, MOSI, SCLK), you can connect them to a 2-to-4 decoder.  That would allow you to select 3x slave devices (fourth one of the decoder outputs is for selecting none of the "payload" devices).